# Rendering an array.map in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an app when using  I generate many drawers to see how it is used  I generate it with a

```
Array(400) .fill(info).map (info => {return <AlbumBox info = {info} />})
```

Obtain the data of an object and pass it in the info variable to generate the drawers.
The structure is in another component only pass the data

Only in console is what is in the arrangement if I put it in a constant

`` `

```
render() {
  const info = {
   img: 'https://Beatles_-Abbey_Road.jpg',
   name: 'The Beatles - "Abbey Road',
   likes: 200,
   comments: 140,
}
const map = Array(1).fill(info).map(info =>{
    return  <AlbumBox info ={info}/>
})

console.warn(map)
return (

  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <AlbumBox info ={info}/>
    {
      Array(500).fill(info).map(info =>{
        return  <AlbumBox info ={info}/>
    })
    }
  </ScrollView>

);
```

` ``

The idea is that I generate on the screen the 500 drawers just sent that variable as a loop

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking. It also seems odd to repeat the **same** object 500 times in an array, which is part of the confusion. What is your actual starting point, and what is your desired result, and where specifically are you stuck? Really want to help, but...

Comment: If you are right
I am new to the use of react, it is only a small test using ScrollView and if I found information but only to react but not how to use it in React Native

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tried the same thing only replaced your components with `p` for simplicity:

```
render() {
const info = {
  img: 'https://Beatles_-Abbey_Road.jpg',
  name: 'The Beatles - "Abbey Road',
  likes: 200,
  comments: 140,
}
return (
  <div>
    {
      Array(500).fill(info).map(info => {
        return <p>{info.name}</p>
      })
    }
  </div>
);
```

}

And its working fine here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jgwxhw) to working example.
Also [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ranaprogrammer/dGhhbm) is a perfectly working snack example of your code.